# Actor name is not unique - AKKA

Tags: java, playframework, akka, actor

I'm using Akka 2.10 with JAVA.

I have a method that takes an Actor reference for me - or create one if there it wasnt before - but some times when I try to create one I receive the following exception:

```
akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [<ActorName>] is not unique!
    at akka.actor.dungeon.ChildrenContainer$NormalChildrenContainer.reserve(ChildrenContainer.scala:130)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.reserveChild(Children.scala:77)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.reserveChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:202)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:552)
```

Of course, I know, the exception is very clear: I'm trying to create more than one actor with the same identifier, but I just do this when I can't find actor's ref. In time:

```
private static ActorRef getActor(String id,Class actor) throws Exception{
    ActorSelection sel = system.actorSelection(system.child(id));
    Timeout t = new Timeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    AskableActorSelection asker = new AskableActorSelection(sel);
    scala.concurrent.Future<Object> fut = asker.ask(new Identify(1), t);
    ActorRef actorClient = null;
    try{
        //Try to get an Actor reference
        ActorIdentity ident = (ActorIdentity)Await.result(fut, t.duration());
        actorClient = ident.getRef();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:"+id);
    } finally{
        //IF I dont found create a new One
        if(actorClient==null){
            actorClient = system.actorOf(Props.create(actor),id);
            //THROWS ME AN EXCEPTION
        }
    }
    return actorClient;
}
```

I wait 4 seconds without an answer... so i create a new one.

I searched the internet through a solution for my case, but without success...

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you create the actor in `Global.onStart`? This way you have sure it will be available when you need it

Comment: In any case, why you want to create it that way precisely? What's the use case? It looks a bit awkward to me.

Comment: @kaktusito, now I'm have created an actor that just make this call, so, i increased the timeout and now I dont have any problems...

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html#reusing-actor-paths) you should not re-use actor paths, even if the actor has died. My guess would be that you've created an actor with that name previously, it died and now can't be found via the actor selection mechanism. In trying to create a new actor with that name you're running into this exception.